# Node stream hangs when emitting error

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I have a stream that's checking a CSV. It works fine except when emitting an error it hangs even after I send the response back.

```
export function ValidateCSV(options) {
  let opt = options;
  if (!(this instanceof ValidateCSV)) return new ValidateCSV(opt);

  if (!opt) opt = {};
  opt.objectMode = true;
  opt.highWaterMark = 1000000;
  Transform.call(this, opt);
}

util.inherits(ValidateCSV, Transform);

ValidateCSV.prototype.destroy = function () {
  this.readable = false;
  this.writable = false;
  this.emit('end');
};

ValidateCSV.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
  // Do some stuff to the chunk
  // Emit error
    if (required.length > 0) {
        this.emit('error', `The following columns are required: ${required.join(', ')}`);
    }

  done();
};
```

I was able to fix it by adding a destroy method but it is still slow and hangs for a few seconds with it. Is there a better way to end/destroy a Transform stream?

```
ValidateCSV.prototype.destroy = function () {
    this.readable = false;
    this.writable = false;
    this.emit('end');
  };
```

EDIT:

Here is how I'm using the stream with busboy:

```
function processMultipart(req, res) {
  const userId = req.query._userId;
  const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers, limits: { files: 1 } });
  const updateId = req.params.id;

  // Transform stream to validate the csv
  const validateCSV = new ValidateCSV();
  validateCSV
    .on('finish', () => {
      // Process the csv
    })
    .on('error', (er) => {
      //Do some logging
      res.status(500).json(er).end();
    });

    // Multipart upload handler
    busboy
      .on('file', (fieldname, file, filename) => {
        dataset.name = fieldname.length > 0 ?
          fieldname : filename.substr(0, filename.indexOf('.csv'));
        file
          .on('error', (er) => {
            //Send Error
          })
          .on('end', () => {
            // Save dataset to mongo
            if (dataset._update) {
              res.status(200).json(dataset).end();
            } else {
              Dataset.create(dataset, (er) => {                
                if (er) {
                  res.status(500).json(er).end();
                } else {
                  res.status(200).json(dataset).end();
                }
              });
            }
          }).pipe(validateCSV);
      });
    req.pipe(busboy);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'hang for a few secs' ? Have you tried to implement it with a through stream (see mississippi module). Can you give an isolated example to reproduce the behavior ?

Comment: It takes a few seconds between when the error is emitted and the stream finally ends and sends the response. I don't really  want to use a module when I don't have to either.

Comment: I added more of how I am implementing the stream. I'm using busboy and piping the file to the stream. The response never closes but I can force it with: res.set('Connection', 'close' ).json(er).end(); But this makes the error function fire 4 times for some reason.

Comment: i ll give it a try, thanks, quick notes, the response end should occur in the end event of validateCsv stream, not file stream. Error event does not necessary destroy the stream, it just emit error, and die __if__ no handler is attached. beware validatecsv.finish event is confusing with the writable finish event (a duplex / transform does not emit such event afaik, and according to the doc)

Comment: oh i forgot, i think one reason it hangs for few seconds is because it is still processing the stream which could be blocking the event loop.

Comment: I tried req.unpipe(busboy), file.unpipe(validateCsv) and it still won't finish sending the response. The request is being made by Superagent, by th way. Is there any way I can inspect the res object to see what is blocking it?